# Creating dependent dropdown menues for plots

Tags: r, plotly, dropdown, chained

I am using R Studio, Plot_ly and Rmarkdown.
The website is setup via blogdown/blogdown_hugo.

In the dataframe "data_local_indices_m" are the columns
"value" (which has the value for every date, which needs to be plotted),
"data_date" (contains the date of the time series),
"country" contains the country name (e.g. AUT) and
"continent" (e.g. Europe).

I want two dropdown menues to change the plotted graph:

1st dropdown should contain the continents.
Based on the selected value in the 1st dropdown menue, in the 
2nd dropdown menue should only appear the countries which have this value.

E.g.:

Dropdown1 (continent):
 - Europe  (this value is selected)

Dropdown2 (country):
- GER
- AUT
- ITA
...

I basically have the two dropdown menues with the respective content but I don't know how to make them dependent on each other.
Furthermore, the whole thing needs to be variable:
If a new country gets added it should automatically appear (in the dropdown "country" and if it has a new continent, this contient should be added in the dropdown "continent")

Managed to create two dropdowns with the respective labels, but they don't depend on each other.

I just leave the code below. It is a very pathetic approach but it creates at least dropdown fields (which are not depending on each other). Please feel free to provide a better example. Maybe use the code just as a basic idea.

```
 continents <- c("Africa", "Asia", "Australia", "Europe", "North America", "South America")

 p2 <- Data_local_indices_m %>% 
  unnest(.sep = "_") %>%
  mutate(data_date=as.yearmon(data_date)) %>% 
  select(country,data_date,IS_data_turb) %>%
  plot_ly(
    mode = 'lines', 
    x = ~data_date, 
    y = ~IS_data_turb,
    transforms = list(
      list(
        type = 'filter', 
        target = ~country, 
        operation = '==', 
        value = unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[1]))) %>% 
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(list(
      active = 3,
         y = 0.9,
         buttons = list(

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
                label = continents[1]),

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
                label = continents[2]), 

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
                label = continents[3]),

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE)),
                label = continents[4]),

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
                label = continents[5]),

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
                label = continents[6]))),

       list(
         #active = 0,
         y = 0.8,
         x = -0.101,
         buttons = list(
             list(
                method = "restyle",
                args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[1]),
                label = unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[1]),

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[2]),
                label = unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[2]),

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[3]),
                label = unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[3]),

           list(method = "restyle",
                args = list("transforms[0].value", unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[4]),
                label = unique(Data_local_indices_m$country)[4])
           )
         )
     )
   )
```

Dropdown1: "Europe"
Dropdown2: only selectable countries which have the continent "Europe"

--> Plot of the respective country is shown.

```
Packages in library ‘/home/rstudio-user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6’:

anytime                     Anything to 'POSIXct' or 'Date' Converter
askpass                     Safe Password Entry for R, Git, and SSH
assertthat                  Easy Pre and Post Assertions
backports                   Reimplementations of Functions Introduced Since R-3.0.0
base64enc                   Tools for base64 encoding
BH                          Boost C++ Header Files
bitops                      Bitwise Operations
blogdown                    Create Blogs and Websites with R Markdown
bookdown                    Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown
Boom                        Bayesian Object Oriented Modeling
BoomSpikeSlab               MCMC for Spike and Slab Regression
broom                       Convert Statistical Analysis Objects into Tidy Tibbles
bsts                        Bayesian Structural Time Series
callr                       Call R from R
cellranger                  Translate Spreadsheet Cell Ranges to Rows and Columns
cli                         Helpers for Developing Command Line Interfaces
clipr                       Read and Write from the System Clipboard
clisymbols                  Unicode Symbols at the R Prompt
colorspace                  A Toolbox for Manipulating and Assessing Colors and
                            Palettes
crayon                      Colored Terminal Output
crosstalk                   Inter-Widget Interactivity for HTML Widgets
cubature                    Adaptive Multivariate Integration over Hypercubes
curl                        A Modern and Flexible Web Client for R
data.table                  Extension of `data.frame`
DBI                         R Database Interface
dbplyr                      A 'dplyr' Back End for Databases
DEoptimR                    Differential Evolution Optimization in Pure R
desc                        Manipulate DESCRIPTION Files
devtools                    Tools to Make Developing R Packages Easier
digest                      Create Compact Hash Digests of R Objects
dplyr                       A Grammar of Data Manipulation
DT                          A Wrapper of the JavaScript Library 'DataTables'
ecodist                     Dissimilarity-Based Functions for Ecological Analysis
ellipsis                    Tools for Working with ...
energy                      E-Statistics: Multivariate Inference via the Energy of
                            Data
evaluate                    Parsing and Evaluation Tools that Provide More Details
                            than the Default
fansi                       ANSI Control Sequence Aware String Functions
fAssets                     Rmetrics - Analysing and Modelling Financial Assets
fBasics                     Rmetrics - Markets and Basic Statistics
fMultivar                   Rmetrics - Analysing and Modeling Multivariate
                            Financial Return Distributions
forcats                     Tools for Working with Categorical Variables (Factors)
forecast                    Forecasting Functions for Time Series and Linear Models
fracdiff                    Fractionally differenced ARIMA aka ARFIMA(p,d,q) models
fs                          Cross-Platform File System Operations Based on 'libuv'
generics                    Common S3 Generics not Provided by Base R Methods
                            Related to Model Fitting
ggplot2                     Create Elegant Data Visualisations Using the Grammar of
                            Graphics
gh                          'GitHub' 'API'
git2r                       Provides Access to Git Repositories
glue                        Interpreted String Literals
googleVis                   R Interface to Google Charts
gss                         General Smoothing Splines
gtable                      Arrange 'Grobs' in Tables
haven                       Import and Export 'SPSS', 'Stata' and 'SAS' Files
hexbin                      Hexagonal Binning Routines
highr                       Syntax Highlighting for R Source Code
hms                         Pretty Time of Day
htmltools                   Tools for HTML
htmlwidgets                 HTML Widgets for R
httpuv                      HTTP and WebSocket Server Library
httr                        Tools for Working with URLs and HTTP
igraph                      Network Analysis and Visualization
ini                         Read and Write '.ini' Files
jomo                        Multilevel Joint Modelling Multiple Imputation
jsonlite                    A Robust, High Performance JSON Parser and Generator
                            for R
knitr                       A General-Purpose Package for Dynamic Report Generation
                            in R
labeling                    Axis Labeling
later                       Utilities for Delaying Function Execution
lazyeval                    Lazy (Non-Standard) Evaluation
lme4                        Linear Mixed-Effects Models using 'Eigen' and S4
lmtest                      Testing Linear Regression Models
lubridate                   Make Dealing with Dates a Little Easier
magrittr                    A Forward-Pipe Operator for R
mailR                       A Utility to Send Emails from R
markdown                    'Markdown' Rendering for R
memoise                     Memoisation of Functions
mice                        Multivariate Imputation by Chained Equations
mime                        Map Filenames to MIME Types
minqa                       Derivative-free optimization algorithms by quadratic
                            approximation
mitml                       Tools for Multiple Imputation in Multilevel Modeling
mnormt                      The Multivariate Normal and t Distributions
modelr                      Modelling Functions that Work with the Pipe
munsell                     Utilities for Using Munsell Colours
mvnormtest                  Normality test for multivariate variables
mvtnorm                     Multivariate Normal and t Distributions
nleqslv                     Solve Systems of Nonlinear Equations
nloptr                      R Interface to NLopt
numDeriv                    Accurate Numerical Derivatives
OECD                        Search and Extract Data from the OECD
openssl                     Toolkit for Encryption, Signatures and Certificates
                            Based on OpenSSL
ordinal                     Regression Models for Ordinal Data
pacman                      Package Management Tool
padr                        Quickly Get Datetime Data Ready for Analysis
pan                         Multiple Imputation for Multivariate Panel or Clustered
                            Data
PerformanceAnalytics        Econometric Tools for Performance and Risk Analysis
pillar                      Coloured Formatting for Columns
pkgbuild                    Find Tools Needed to Build R Packages
pkgconfig                   Private Configuration for 'R' Packages
pkgload                     Simulate Package Installation and Attach
plogr                       The 'plog' C++ Logging Library
plotly                      Create Interactive Web Graphics via 'plotly.js'
plyr                        Tools for Splitting, Applying and Combining Data
prettyunits                 Pretty, Human Readable Formatting of Quantities
processx                    Execute and Control System Processes
progress                    Terminal Progress Bars
promises                    Abstractions for Promise-Based Asynchronous Programming
ps                          List, Query, Manipulate System Processes
purrr                       Functional Programming Tools
quadprog                    Functions to Solve Quadratic Programming Problems
Quandl                      API Wrapper for Quandl.com
quantmod                    Quantitative Financial Modelling Framework
R.methodsS3                 S3 Methods Simplified
R.oo                        R Object-Oriented Programming with or without
                            References
R.utils                     Various Programming Utilities
R6                          Encapsulated Classes with Reference Semantics
RApiDatetime                R API Datetime
rcmdcheck                   Run 'R CMD check' from 'R' and Capture Results
RColorBrewer                ColorBrewer Palettes
Rcpp                        Seamless R and C++ Integration
RcppEigen                   'Rcpp' Integration for the 'Eigen' Templated Linear
                            Algebra Library
RCurl                       General Network (HTTP/FTP/...) Client Interface for R
readr                       Read Rectangular Text Data
readxl                      Read Excel Files
rematch                     Match Regular Expressions with a Nicer 'API'
remotes                     R Package Installation from Remote Repositories,
                            Including 'GitHub'
reprex                      Prepare Reproducible Example Code via the Clipboard
reshape2                    Flexibly Reshape Data: A Reboot of the Reshape Package
rJava                       Low-Level R to Java Interface
RJSONIO                     Serialize R Objects to JSON, JavaScript Object Notation
rlang                       Functions for Base Types and Core R and 'Tidyverse'
                            Features
rmarkdown                   Dynamic Documents for R
robustbase                  Basic Robust Statistics
rprojroot                   Finding Files in Project Subdirectories
rsdmx                       Tools for Reading SDMX Data and Metadata
rstudioapi                  Safely Access the RStudio API
rvest                       Easily Harvest (Scrape) Web Pages
scales                      Scale Functions for Visualization
selectr                     Translate CSS Selectors to XPath Expressions
servr                       A Simple HTTP Server to Serve Static Files or Dynamic
                            Documents
sessioninfo                 R Session Information
shiny                       Web Application Framework for R
sn                          The Skew-Normal and Related Distributions Such as the
                            Skew-t
sourcetools                 Tools for Reading, Tokenizing and Parsing R Code
stabledist                  Stable Distribution Functions
stringi                     Character String Processing Facilities
stringr                     Simple, Consistent Wrappers for Common String
                            Operations
sys                         Powerful and Reliable Tools for Running System Commands
                            in R
tibble                      Simple Data Frames
tidyquant                   Tidy Quantitative Financial Analysis
tidyr                       Easily Tidy Data with 'spread()' and 'gather()'
                            Functions
tidyselect                  Select from a Set of Strings
tidyverse                   Easily Install and Load the 'Tidyverse'
timeDate                    Rmetrics - Chronological and Calendar Objects
timeSeries                  Rmetrics - Financial Time Series Objects
timetk                      A Tool Kit for Working with Time Series in R
tinytex                     Helper Functions to Install and Maintain 'TeX Live',
                            and Compile 'LaTeX' Documents
tseries                     Time Series Analysis and Computational Finance
tsibble                     Tidy Temporal Data Frames and Tools
TTR                         Technical Trading Rules
ucminf                      General-Purpose Unconstrained Non-Linear Optimization
uncertaintymeasures         Functions to create uncertainty measures using
                            turbulence
urca                        Unit Root and Cointegration Tests for Time Series Data
usethis                     Automate Package and Project Setup
utf8                        Unicode Text Processing
vctrs                       Vector Helpers
viridisLite                 Default Color Maps from 'matplotlib' (Lite Version)
whisker                     {{mustache}} for R, logicless templating
withr                       Run Code 'With' Temporarily Modified Global State
xfun                        Miscellaneous Functions by 'Yihui Xie'
XML                         Tools for Parsing and Generating XML Within R and
                            S-Plus
xml2                        Parse XML
xopen                       Open System Files, 'URLs', Anything
xtable                      Export Tables to LaTeX or HTML
xts                         eXtensible Time Series
yaml                        Methods to Convert R Data to YAML and Back
zeallot                     Multiple, Unpacking, and Destructuring Assignment
zoo                         S3 Infrastructure for Regular and Irregular Time Series
                            (Z's Ordered Observations)

Packages in library ‘/opt/R/3.6.0/lib/R/library’:

base                        The R Base Package
boot                        Bootstrap Functions (Originally by Angelo Canty for S)
class                       Functions for Classification
cluster                     "Finding Groups in Data": Cluster Analysis Extended
                            Rousseeuw et al.
codetools                   Code Analysis Tools for R
compiler                    The R Compiler Package
datasets                    The R Datasets Package
foreign                     Read Data Stored by 'Minitab', 'S', 'SAS', 'SPSS',
                            'Stata', 'Systat', 'Weka', 'dBase', ...
graphics                    The R Graphics Package
grDevices                   The R Graphics Devices and Support for Colours and
                            Fonts
grid                        The Grid Graphics Package
KernSmooth                  Functions for Kernel Smoothing Supporting Wand & Jones
                            (1995)
lattice                     Trellis Graphics for R
MASS                        Support Functions and Datasets for Venables and
                            Ripley's MASS
Matrix                      Sparse and Dense Matrix Classes and Methods
methods                     Formal Methods and Classes
mgcv                        Mixed GAM Computation Vehicle with Automatic Smoothness
                            Estimation
nlme                        Linear and Nonlinear Mixed Effects Models
nnet                        Feed-Forward Neural Networks and Multinomial Log-Linear
                            Models
parallel                    Support for Parallel computation in R
rpart                       Recursive Partitioning and Regression Trees
spatial                     Functions for Kriging and Point Pattern Analysis
splines                     Regression Spline Functions and Classes
stats                       The R Stats Package
stats4                      Statistical Functions using S4 Classes
survival                    Survival Analysis
tcltk                       Tcl/Tk Interface
tools                       Tools for Package Development
utils                       The R Utils Package
```

Comment: On my ipad so cannot give full answer,but,look at updateSelectInput(). You would have input1 choices = unique(df$continent). Your input2 would be initially blank. In server update input2 to return the value of countries (unique) from your dataframe.

Comment: This seems to be a shiny function. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use Shiney, only plotly (or something else that is free and doesn't need a server). 

Is there any plotly-equivalent?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi! When you say doesnt need a server, does this apply to shiny.io https://www.shinyapps.io?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about that. I have just the information not use shiny because this would create costs for my supervisors. Therefore, I am trying to handel this with plot_ly.

Comment: I tend to be a statistics and R programming guy so my efforts at these business user-interface types of questions are only extended to questions where I can cut-and-paste a code block and see what appears. You obviously are using a bunch of packages but have no library calls. You cannot possibly expect us to replicate your entire library of packages can you? Really now.  (You might try using `sessionInfo()` .)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really big. I will use a simple example to illustrate the idea.

You can temporarily save the choosen continent. After that you can select only countries that correspond to the choosen continent, so that in the secound drop down menu it is only possible to choose between the right countries. Something like this:

```
# some data
df <- data.frame(continent= c("europe", "europe", "asia", "asia"), country= c("italy", "germany", "china", "india"))
df
  continent country
1    europe   italy
2    europe germany
3      asia   china
4      asia   india

# now choose some continent (you will make this as a dropdown menu)
continent_choosen <- "europe"

# choosing from the possible countries
df$country[df$continent == continent_choosen]
italy germany
```

The same idea goes on for possible cities or possible suburbs and so on.

Comment: Hi schwantke,

thanks for your answer.

This is exactly what I want to achieve.

But I don't know how to implement this in the dropdown menus:
1. How do I save the selection of the user in the first field (continents)
2. How do I manage that every country/continent in the respective column is added as item in the dropdown field?

Furthermore, the country/continent list is permanent extenden so I need a flexible solution. But in a loop I can't execute a function (per vector enty), as far as I know.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @StableSong I would recommend rephrasing the question and leaving all out that is not really necessery to answer the question. Try to keep it as simple as possible. Also, use `library(...)` to make clear what libraries you use.

Comment: I updated the question and included library(). Many thanks for your help.